# Excel VBA Copy from one worksheet to a new one whilst keeping formatting and values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy a table from one worksheet to new one created when running the macro whilst keeping the data formatting and cell formatting. I've used the following code which will copy from the worksheet to a specified one, and keeps most of the formatting apart from the cell heights and width.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E1")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10").Copy
With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E1")
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```